# Private Etherum to work like Main Net

Tags: private-blockchain

I want my private Ethereum blockchain to work like the Main net, I want to fix the number of mined ether (Set Max Cap over minded ether), and don't want that miners earn by mining empty blocks.

Comment: What is your question? If you ask if this is possible then the answer is "yes, it is possible". But changes to the consensus algorithm like requiring blocks to be non empty of a different reward value might require code changes.